# What is wrong with my Angular 13 Subscribe?

Tags: angular, observable

I've been fighting this thing all night, and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've tried lots of different things, but haven't been successful yet. I'm using Angular 13.
Here is my NetworkService:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { map, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Inputs } from '../_models/Inputs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NetworkService {
  private networkSource = new ReplaySubject<any>();
  Network$ = this.networkSource.asObservable();
  network: any;
  private helloSource = new ReplaySubject<any>();
  Hello$ = this.helloSource.asObservable();
  hello: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getNetworkInfo(inputs: Inputs) {
    var date = inputs.FillDate.toISOString().split('T')[0];
    var url = `/price/pricenetworkinfo/?testMode=true&priceNetworkName=${inputs.PriceNetworkName}&fillDate=${date}`;

    return this.http.get(`${environment.baseApiUrl}${url}`)
      .pipe(map((response: any) => {
        this.network = response;
        this.networkSource.next(this.network);
      }));
  }
}
```

Here is the method that calls it:

```
  getData() {
    this.networkService.getNetworkInfo(this.model)
      .subscribe(x => {
        this.networkInfo = x;
      }).add(() => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.networkInfo));
      });

    this.enumService.getEnums()
      .subscribe(x => {
        this.enums = x;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.enums));
      });
  }
```

Now.... The call to `getEnums` works when it is in the `ngOnInit` function, but not in this function (this function is called by a button click). And the `getNetworkInfo` call doesn't work here, but I can't move it to the `ngOnInit` function because it requires input before being called.

The two services both work, fetching the requested data when called, but the calling component does not get that data back. I can see it in the dev tools, but stepping through, the `x` in the subscribe method is undefined.

I have another project where I'm doing pretty much the same thing (different services, but set up the same way), and that project works fine. This one, though, I have to be missing something really stupid. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Adding the enum service and button template as requested below:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { map, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EnumService {
  private enumSource = new ReplaySubject<any>();
  Enums$ = this.enumSource.asObservable();
  enums: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getEnums() {
    let enums = sessionStorage.getItem('Enums');
    if (!enums) {
      return this.http.get(environment.baseApiUrl + '/utility/getuienums')
        .pipe(map((response: any) => {
          this.enums = response;
          this.enumSource.next(this.enums);
          sessionStorage.setItem('Enums', JSON.stringify(this.enums));
        }))
    }
    else {
      this.enumSource.next(JSON.parse(enums));
      return this.Enums$;
    }
  }
}
```

```
<div class="col-md-2 d-grid">
              <button class="btn btn-lg btn-danger"
                      (click)="getData()">Send</button>
       </div>
```

Note that with the enums I'm saving them to session storage, because they will be reused as people use the site (this is an application people within our company use). I do note that now that I've changed `map` to `tap` as suggested in the offered answer, I do get results back from the NetworkService, and I do not have logged output from the EnumService. I'll have to look into the `tap` function, as I'd never seen it before.

Comment: In what way does it fail? Network error, observable never completes, something else?

Comment: Are you using the (click) event binding to call the method in your template? Can you post your Template please.

Comment: Can you also post the enumService.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen, no errors. The x in the subscribe function was just undefined.

Comment: @AlvinSaldanha, added those for you. It looks like map was the wrong function for what I was doing, and tap is the right one, as using tap in both services I get what I expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You `getNetworkInfo` function returns an observable that does not emit any data. The reason is that you do not return anything from `map` method.
Try to change the operator to `tap` in order to perform side effects (like you did) without changing the emitted values.

```
return this.http.get(`${environment.baseApiUrl}${url}`)
  .pipe(tap((response: any) => {
    this.network = response;
    this.networkSource.next(this.network);
}));
```

Comment: This did it. Thank you. Now I'll have to go look into that method, as I hadn't heard of it.

Comment: `map` is used to map each emitted value to a new one. You could also put `return response` at the end of your map function, which will have the same result (as the emitted value is just mapped to itself), but `tap` is the best practice in your case.